# Getting JedisConnectionException in one particular operation

Tags: redis, jedis

I am trying to delete keys of a specific pattern from redis server but while executing it, it shows:

```
redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Unexpected end of stream.
    at redis.clients.util.RedisInputStream.ensureFill(RedisInputStream.java:199)
    at redis.clients.util.RedisInputStream.readByte(RedisInputStream.java:40)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.process(Protocol.java:153)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.read(Protocol.java:218)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.readProtocolWithCheckingBroken(Connection.java:341)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.getBinaryMultiBulkReply(Connection.java:277)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Jedis.keys(Jedis.java:284)
```

For your reference, my server timeout value is 0 and jedis version which I have been using is 2.10.2.
Following is the code snippet which I am trying to execute:

```
try {
    Set<String> keys = jedis.keys(pattern);
    jedis.del(keys.toArray(new String[keys.size()]));
} catch(Exception e) {
    log.error("Failed to delete key entry for pattern {0}", pattern);
    throw e;
}
```

here pattern is the string we are trying to delete.

Any suggestion to resolve the error?

=================================================================

UPDATE-1:

1. The code is running fine in local, no issues with any jedis function.
2. When running on remote server, other functions are getting executed correctly except this delete keys method. Precisely while executing jedis.keys()

Comment: Have you tried using a custom JedisPoolConfig to set the minEvictableIdleTimeMillis to desired value? This will ensure idle connections are released from Jedis connection pool

Comment: Agreed with **@TomCools**, [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45048793/3679900) says it worked for them

Comment: Here's the [link](https://github.com/xetorthio/jedis/issues/2187#issue-602415935) to issue-thread on `Jedis`'s repo

Comment: @TomCools  the main issue here is that we are using NutCracker on top of redis which i suppose doesn't allow Keys command. Is there any alternative to get all the keys by pattern?

Comment: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61319057/3679900)'s the follow-up question

Comment: were you able to solve the problem? if yes, please consider adding your resolution as an answer (for reference of others)

Comment: Not able to solve the issue.

Comment: @Chanfool21 use SCAN to list keys with a specific pattern.