# Not able to execute Redis keys or scan method to fetch keys by pattern on a redis server with nutcracker on it

Tags: redis, jedis, twemproxy

I am trying to delete keys by pattern from redis server with nutcracker as proxy but it shows error while executing jedis.keys which I am using in my java code. 
It doesn't allow keys and scan method that I know. I am using simple set method to make a key-value entry in the redis. So can anyone suggest any alternative method to fetch keys by pattern from redis?

Stacktrace of the exception:

```
redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Unexpected end of stream.
    at redis.clients.util.RedisInputStream.ensureFill(RedisInputStream.java:199)
    at redis.clients.util.RedisInputStream.readByte(RedisInputStream.java:40)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.process(Protocol.java:153)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.read(Protocol.java:218)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.readProtocolWithCheckingBroken(Connection.java:341)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.getBinaryMultiBulkReply(Connection.java:277)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Jedis.keys(Jedis.java:284)
```

Server timeout value is set to be 0 and jedis version which I have been using is 2.10.2. Following is the code snippet which I am trying to execute:

```
try {
    Set<String> keys = jedis.keys(pattern);
    jedis.del(keys.toArray(new String[keys.size()]));
} catch(Exception e) {
    log.error("Failed to delete key entry for pattern {0}", pattern);
    throw e;
}
```

Comment: were you able to solve the problem? if yes, please consider adding your resolution as an answer (for reference of others)